# What kind of wire can you use in your home?

Tags: new-home

Can you use MC cable in a house?

I am wiring can lights.  Also how many lines can go to a junction box?

I have a 125A box, what kind of wire would I need to run?

Comment: So Tom, you've asked a question that required serious editing to be comprehensible to the average user of English, and you've asked a number of questions that are only loosely related.  This is not well suited to our format of question and answer where we try to focus on ONE question at a time.  Would you like to take another run at it and break these questions up?  Some of the questions seem to suggest that you really may not be right to do wiring on your own.  Electricity is very dangerous and you're touching on particularly dangerous sub-topics.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can wire a house with MC if allowed by local code Metal clad is listed for exposed or concealed , indoors or outdoors per NEC 330.10. . How many lines to a junction box depends on the wire size and the box size NEC 314.16. Your 125 amp question is unclear are you asking about the service? Or branch circuits coming out of the box. I would suggest getting a house wiring book because at this point based on your question I believe you need to do a large amount of reading.